# python3 command not found in docker container

Tags: python, c#, docker

I have a .Net Core API which runs inside a Docker container. That is the Dockerfile:

```
# Stage 1

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /build
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app
COPY PythonScript/Script.py /app

# Stage 2
FROM python:slim
ENV PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/usr/local/bin"
ENV PYTHON_VERSION=3.9.4
ENV PYTHON_PIP_VERSION=21.0.1
ENV PYTHON_GET_PIP_URL=https://github.com/pypa/get-pip/raw/29f37dbe6b3842ccd52d61816a3044173962ebeb/public/get-pip.py
ENV PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256=e03eb8a33d3b441ff484c56a436ff10680479d4bd14e59268e67977ed40904de


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS final

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app .
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "BankAccountAPI.dll"]
```

I use the `python:slim` image in order to be able to execute python commands.

The API calls a python command via bash like this:

```
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.FileName = "/bin/bash";
var command = $"python3 --version";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-c \" " + command + " \"";
process.Start();
```

When I run the container it tells me the following:

```
/bin/bash: python3: command not found
```

What do I have to do so that the `python3` command is known?

Comment: How about `python` without 3?

Comment: nope not working either

Comment: You would better check the python path and add to ENV. Something like `which python`

Comment: `python` doesn't exist in the `final` stage, your'e not installing it or copying it from the "Stage 2" layer. `python` isn't installed by default in the `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1` image.